# Frame–Stewart algorithm implementation in prolog

Tags: algorithm, prolog, towers-of-hanoi

I am trying to code the solver for the Towers of Hanoi problem with four pegs.

```
%hanoi4(NrOfDisks, From, To, Seged1, Seged2, ListOfSteps)

hanoi4(1,From, To, _,_,[From -> To]). 

hanoi4(Disks,From, To, Seged1, Seged2, ListOfSteps):-
   Pozitiv is 2*Disks+1,
   Pozitiv > 0,                 
   K is Disks-round(floor(sqrt(Pozitiv))+1),
   hanoi4(K,From,Seged1,Seged2,To,Steps1),
   hanoi4(Disks-K,From,To,Seged2,Seged1,Steps2),
   append(Steps1,Steps2,Steps),
   hanoi4(K,Seged1,To,From,Seged2,Steps3),
   append(Steps,Steps3,ListOfSteps).
```

I put the 2*Disks+1 expression's value into the "Pozitiv" variable, because I got errors when I wrote it directly in the sqrt predicate. (sqrt/1: Arithmetic: evaluation error: `undefined')
I tried to follow the steps of the [Frame–Stewart algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#Frame.E2.80.93Stewart_algorithm).

Comment: Be aware that in Prolog, a term is not evaluated as an expression except when explicitly called for using `is/2`, CLP(FD) operations, and some numerical expression comparators. So `hanoi4(Disks-K,From,To,Seged2,Seged1,Steps2)` does *not* perform the subtaction for `Disks-K`. You would need something like `Disks1 is Disks-K` followed by `hanoi4(Disks1,From,To,Seged2,Seged1,Steps2)`. Not sure why you need `round(floor(...))` since `floor/1` will result in an integer, and `round` will do nothing at that point.

Comment: I'm very thankful for your remarks! 
I corrected the predicate calling and got rid of the ceil+round combo.
After that I found out I didn't followed the instructions of the algorithm. It was needed another function which handles the case of the bottom (n-k) disks, so when we deal with them, we don't disturb the first k disks. 
Now everything works perfectly.